# Qt & SqlLite - wrong path to database

Tags: c++, qt, sqlite

I'm actually working with Qt & SqlLite and my problem is that even a request totaly working on sqllite3.exe doesnt work into my program. I keep getting an error message I set up. I wonder if it's really a code problem because I can actually connect to my database and requests works fine when trying them into the sqllite3.exe.

Path to database :

```
SQLLITE\musclelayout
```

DataHandler.cpp - constructor (edited after many usefull comments)

```
DataHandler::DataHandler(QMainWindow* mw, const QString& path)
{
   databaseIsOpen = false;

   database = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE");
   database.setDatabaseName(path);

   qDebug() << "Opening database:" << path << "from" << QDir::currentPath();
   qDebug() << "Does the file exist:" << QFileInfo::exists(path);

   if(database.open())
   {
       qDebug() << "Database opened. Tables:" << database.tables();
       databaseIsOpen = true;
   }
   else
   {
       QString msgTitle("Cannot login to '" + path + "'");
       QMessageBox::StandardButton alertMsg;
       alertMsg = QMessageBox::warning(mw, msgTitle, database.lastError().text(), QMessageBox::Ok);
   }

}
```

The path is totally wrong :

```
Opening database: "SQLLITEmusclelayout" from "C:/Users/Tong3/Desktop/DEV/build-muscleLayout-Qt_5_8_0_mingw53_32-Debug"
Does the file exist: true
Database opened. Tables: ()
```

But i cannot write 'SQLLITE\'(won't compile) and the path doesn't go where my project is.
The real url :

```
C:\Users\Tong3\Desktop\DEV\muscleLayout\SQLLITE\musclelayout
```

DataHandler - getTrainedMucleList()

```
vector<QString> DataHandler::getTrainedMuscleList(QMainWindow* mw)
{
    vector<QString> tmp_array;

    QSqlQuery query;

    if(databaseIsOpen)
    {
        if(query.exec("SELECT * FROM trainedMuscle"))
        {
            while(query.next())
            {
                tmp_array.push_back(query.value("muscleName").toString());
            }
        }
        else
        {
            QString msgTitle("Cannot load muscle list");
            QMessageBox::StandardButton alertMsg;
            alertMsg = QMessageBox::warning(mw, msgTitle, query.lastError().text(), QMessageBox::Ok);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        QString msgTitle("Cannot login to database");
        QMessageBox::StandardButton alertMsg;
        alertMsg = QMessageBox::warning(mw, msgTitle, database.lastError().text(), QMessageBox::Ok);
    }

    return tmp_array;
}
```

Thanks for taking time to read my newbie code,
have a nice day.

Comment: Use `query.lastError().text();` to check the error message.

Comment: What is the path?

Comment: The error is "unable to find trainedMuscle". but the table does exist ! Path is "SQLLITE\musclelayout". The database is open successfuly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### About QSqlQuery

You are not using QSqlQuery correctly.

The constructor `QSqlQuery(const QString &query = QString(), QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase())` executes the given `query`. Quoting the documentation:

> Constructs a QSqlQuery object using the SQL query and the database db.
>   If db is not specified, or is invalid, the application's default
>   database is used. **If query is not an empty string, it will be
>   executed.**

While `bool QSqlQuery::exec()` is for prepared query. Still quoting the documentation:

> Executes a **previously prepared SQL query**. Returns true if the query
>   executed successfully; otherwise returns false.

You could use these examples instead:

```
// The most complete form as you could bind values between prepare() and exec()
QSqlQuery query;
query.prepare("SELECT * FROM trainedMuscle");
query.exec();

// A shorter form for when you do not need to bind values
QSqlQuery query;
query.exec("SELECT * FROM trainedMuscle");

// The shortest form, the query is executed in the constructor,
// you do not need to call exec(). Use lastError() to check execution.
QSqlQuery query("SELECT * FROM trainedMuscle");
```

---

### About SQLite

Also SQLite is serverless (https://www.sqlite.org/serverless.html), so you can change the way you open the database as you do not need to set a server:

```
database = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE");
database.setDatabaseName(path);

if(database.open())
...
```

Also given your comments, I suspect that you have an issue with your paths, so you could add a little debug outputs to ensure you are opening the correct SQLite database file:

```
database = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE");
database.setDatabaseName(path);

qDebug() << "Opening database:" << path << "from" << QDir::currentPath();
qDebug() << "Does the file exist:" << QFileInfo::exists(path);

if(database.open())
{
    qDebug() << "Database opened. Tables:" << database.tables();
    ....
}
```

---

### About writing strings with backslashes in C++

It is normal that something like `QString path = "SQLLITE\"` will not compile. The backslash is an escape character, if you want to put a litteral backslash in a string you need to double it. If you want to write a Windows path you can write:

```
QString path = "C:\\Users\\Tong3\\Desktop\\DEV\\muscleLayout\\SQLLITE\\musclelayout"; // Actually contains "C:\Users\Tong3\Desktop\DEV\muscleLayout\SQLLITE\musclelayout"
```

But if you are using Qt you can write Windows path using the forward slash as directory separator like so:

```
QString path = "C:/Users/Tong3/Desktop/DEV/muscleLayout/SQLLITE/musclelayout";
```

---

### About Working Directory

The reason why "the path doesn't go where my project is" is that the working directory of a program is initially set from where the program is executed. It is neither related to where the executable is nor to where your sources are.

When you use relative paths in your program they are interpreted relatively to this working directory.

As a developer you have no control what the initial working directory will be, as it depends on how the user will launch the program. You can however change it during the execution of the program.

In your case the working directory is `C:/Users/Tong3/Desktop/DEV/build-muscleLayout-Qt_5_8_0_mingw53_32-Debug`. This option can be changed in QtCreator within the "Projects" tab, in the "Run Settings".

However I think you would be better off not using relative paths but instead putting your SQLite database alongside your app (see [QCoreApplication::apllicationDirPath()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcoreapplication.html#applicationDirPath)) or in the AppData folder (see [QStandardPaths::writableLocation(QStandardPaths::AppDataLocation)](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstandardpaths.html#writableLocation)) depending if the user will need to have write access to the database.

Comment: This changed the error message I got with `query.lastError().text(` : `no such table trainedMuscle`. But the table does exist.

Comment: You can use `QSqlDatabase::tables()` to list the tables in your database when you open it. It might simply be a path issue ; what is the value of  `path` in your first code sample? If you set it with something like `path = "SQLLITE\\musclelayout"`, first use `/`instead of `\` even on Windows, Qt takes care of it, secondly you have a relative path and it might end up connecting to the wrong database. You can check the current directory with `QDir::currentPath()`.

Comment: / : out of memory of database. \\ : same error. Only '\' works. Looks like i really connect to the database. I'm sorry i have no idea how to use QSqlDatabase::tables(). does it input values in the prompt ?

Comment: @SanchezTanguy Come on... `QSqlDatabase::tables()` is a function, documented in Qt documentation, it returns a `QStringList` containing the table names. http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsqldatabase.html#tables If you want to output debug info in the terminal look at `QDebug`

Comment: Why can't you escape '\' ?

Comment: When I do, I got the message `out of memory opening database`

Comment: The problem might not be withe the \\ directly. If you got your paths wrong then when you want to open `SQLLITE\\musclelayout` (or `SQLLITE/musclelayout`), you are trying to open the file `musclelayout` within the `SQLLITE` directory. If `musclelayout` does not exist, SQLite will create it, but if even `SQLLITE` does not exist, it will NOT create it and will report an error. Whereas if you have `path = "SQLLITE\musclelayout"` SQLite will simply  create an empty database file `SQLLITEmusclelayout`.

Comment: Yes i actually saw that `SQLLITEmusclelayout` file ! Do you have any idea how to resolve that ? Sorry i'm really bad with path. When I was on linux i was like "holy shit weird relative path everywhere"..

Comment: @SanchezTanguy The problem is not with path, but that you do not know how to write a string with a literal backslashes in C++ and how they are used as escape characters. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! I had one last question : I cannot put a relative path ? This software is for me but i don't know.. If I want to share it or something. I need a relative path there. How do I redefine the path ? I tried with '.' linux style but didnt worked.

Comment: I think the answer to your questions is in my last edit. Anyway if you want to share you application, you need to package it. You can start by looking at http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/windows-deployment.html . For your SQLite database there are many way you can choose to deploy it. If it is read only you can distribute it alongside your exe or use Qt resource system. If the end user need to modify it you will need to save it somewhere where the user will have write access like its AppData folder.

Comment: Really thanks for taking your time. I'm sorry i don't understand where the solution is. you wrote a full path (>_<). But I'm gonna try to find out so I will put it as answered. Thanks you again for your time :) .